# Conditional checks for different variables

Tags: c, conditional-statements

I have a function which sets a variable based on another variable.

```
if(!button_x.on)
   button_x.on = 1;
if(!button_y.on)
   button_y.on = 1;
if(!button_z.on)
   button_z.on = 1;
.
.
.
```

If it is x, y, z, …. is determined only at runtime. Having multiple such conditions for various(100s) different cases does not look good. Is there a better way to go about this in C?

---

EDIT:
I should have better framed my example above.

```
if (!structureA.visited)            
    visit_structureA(); // does some operation
if (!structureB.visited)            
visit_structureB();
if (!structureC.visited)            
visit_structureC();
```

.
.
.

The number of structures and the name of the structure is not known at compile time. But the structure names follow a specific pattern shown above. It is known only at runtime. 
I tried using macros something like:

```
#define VISIT(str) \
    if (!structure##str.visited) \
        visit_structure##str();

//In the function:
// str = 'known at runtime' 
  VISIT(str);
```

But this would not work for obvious reason that preprocessor directives are replaced during compile time and not runtime. I am not sure if there is a better way for this?

Comment: Do you need to toggle between the states ? i.e., if it is ON turn it OFF and vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, you set a variable value according to the same variable, not another one, if this is the case, and you want to change it from 0 to 1 and vice versa, you can do it without condition:

```
button_x.on = !button_x.on;
```

If you have many of those with the same idea of behavior, consider using array and itertating it.

Comment: I would have exactly said this if OP agreed to my comment :)

Answer (score 1):

In C, the following condition:

```
if (!x)
  x = 1;
```

is equivalent to:

```
x = 1;
```

if the variable is boolean (on/off), which I assume is the case if we are talking about buttons.

Comment: +1, the name of the struct member seems to imply the value is boolean and in that case the condition is an overhead. If the value is not boolean the OP should precise it and may think to change the name of the struct member to a less confusing name.

Comment: @BinyaminSharet - please see my clearly-stated assumption that the variables were boolean (as buttons are in the habit of being).

Comment: @NathanWiebe - I'm sorry, but it wasn't clear to me when I red it. my mistake :-/